# scapy "TypeError: 'IP' object is not callable"

Tags: python, ip, scapy

in my Scapy Script I get an Error, I cannot find a reason for.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *
from settings import *

#Create  Layer-2 Frame. 
l2 = Ether( dst=dst, src=src, type=2048) #dst and src from settings
pkt = IP(dst=dst)/ICMP(type=8)/Raw(load=("X"*10000))
#Create some big pings:
for i in range(10000,10020):
    frags = fragment(pkt) #create Fragments    
    for fragment in frags:
        sendp(l2/fragment, iface=iface)
    print("i: " + str(i))
```

Scapy sends one whole packet and after that, I become the error message:

> TypeError: 'IP' object is not callable

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the `fragment` function with a `for` loop variable, so `fragment` becomes a non-callable object in the next iteration of the outer loop.

You should rename the `fragment` variable to something else:

```
for frag in frags:
    sendp(l2/frag, iface=iface)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be defining `IP` with a different, non-callable value in `settings.py`, so the `IP` class defined by the `scapy` package gets overridden. You can resolve this issue by renaming the `IP` variable in `settings.py` to something else. Alternatively, you can do `import settings` instead of `from settings import *` and then refer to the `IP` variable in `settings.py` as `settings.IP`.

Comment: no, in  settings.py  is nothing like this. Just the variable dst and iface.

Comment: Can you tell us what you see in the output when you add `print(IP)` before the line `pkt = ...`?

Comment: I see **<class 'scapy.layers.inet.IP'>**